# invalid character '_' in Bundle Identifier

Tags: xcode, bundle, suppress-warnings

Build warning:

```
invalid character '_' in Bundle Identifier at column 17. This string must be a uniform type identifier (UTI) that contains only alphanumeric (A-Z,a-z,0-9), hyphen (-), and period (.) characters.
```

This warning is occurring when building a 3rd party framework that we cannot modify. Is there a way to make Xcode (5.0.2) suppress the warning?

Note: this app will not be going into the App Store.

Thanks!

Comment: File a bug report with the 3rd party so they can fix the framework for everyone.

Answer (score 9):

Bundle Identifier present in plist should contain only *alphanumeric (A-Z,a-z,0-9), hypen (-), and period (.) characters*. You cannot add characters other than specified. Hence, prompting an warning.

[image: Screenshot 0]
[image: Screenshot 1]
Now, **remove underscore ( _ ) character from Bundle Identifier** to suppress warning.

Comment: it's very unfortunate that Apple decided on this, because just about everywhere else in software underscore is a valid part of an identifier...